# AWS SES Verified mail but still getting an error 554

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am having issues with sending email from a verified email.
(asking it here, as for some reason I can't ask in AWS forum)

Setup:
The email *XXX.mydomain.com* is verified.

domain *mydomain.com* is verified (in domain list).

I am testing through 'Send email Test' in AWS.
The sender (from) is the verified email.

When I send to +DDVVF@mydomain.com+, it's fine (email is sent).

When I send to a different email (*my-client@other-domain.com*), I get an error message, containing:

> Email address is not verified. (Request ID:
>   73ee3c33-ef6b-11e5-a37e-e5f5988f938c)

Should I also verify the **TO** emails I want to send?
It doesn't seem scalable, as I don't want to verify each **TO** separately.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you still using the [Sandbox](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html)? They are restricted if so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are still in the sandbox , you need to log in request with AWS to move you to Production.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html